# Searching in Codeigniter using URL?

Tags: codeigniter, uri

Search form:

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>product/search" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="proname" />
        <button class="submit_btn" type="submit">TÌM KIẾM</button>
    </form>
```

My Controller:

```
function search(){
    $product_name = trim($this->input->post('proname'));
    $search = array('name' => $product_name);
    $param = $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($search);             
    if($product_name == '/'){
        redirect('product/search_result/'.$param);
    }else{
        redirect('product/search_result/'.$param);
    }
}

function search_result(){

    $result = $this->uri->segment_array();      
    $data['page_title'] = 'Result';     
    $data['pro'] = $this->data_mod->search_array('ebook',array('e_title_vn' => $result[4]));
    $data['keyword'] = $result[4];
    $this->load->view('search_result',$data);
}
```

When I echo the keyword (as $this->uri->segment(4)), example:

```
từ khóa
```

it will show

```
t%E1%BB%AB%20kh%C3%B3a
```

I don't know why, can anyone help me?

(I'm bad at English, so sorry. my language is Vietnamese.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$param` that you add on your redirect URL will be encoded, you should use

```
urldecode($this->uri->segment(4));
```

to get it displayed right.